# PHP $_SESSION being saved, but cannot be retrieved without a time delay

Tags: php, session

First of all, I tried to find an answer on SO, but couldn't find anything that would be specific to the problem I am having.

Now, the problem is as follows:

1. I send a JSON string with AJAX to the server, everything is on the same domain, same server
2. I decode the JSON string, implode it using commas as separators, get a string as a return and save that string into a $_SESSION variable
3. For testing purposes I even do `print_r` on the $_SESSION variable right after setting it and I can see that it is being set
4. When I try and use that $_SESSION variable on a different page, it doesn't exist anymore. The $_SESSION can be accessed, but it's just that variable that doesn't exist.

And here's the best part:

**It works if I put `sleep(1)` before setting the $_SESSION variable or do anything that takes a long time to execute**

Comment: Do you call session_start in the second page?

Comment: Yes, I do. That's what I meant when I said that the $_SESSION can be retrieved on the second page, but it doesn't contain the one variable I set

Comment: what about session_write_close() right after setting $_SESSION on first page?

Comment: I tried session_write_close() already, but it didn't help.

Comment: When exactly are you calling the other page? Immediately afterwards? How - through Ajax, or by navigating to it in the browser?

Comment: And I am just curious, how did you come up with the sleep solution?

Comment: @Pekka I'm issuing the AJAX call, saving the information to the SESSION and then navigating to the second page in the browser, nothing extraordinary about that. I've even waited for a couple of seconds before I do that, but it doesn't change anything, unless I do sleep(1) before setting the SESSION variable

Comment: @Headshota I tried using a mail function to see how many times a function is run, and I noticed that it helped. So the only conclusion I came to was a time delay

Comment: Are you using the default session handlers or have you written your own?

Comment: @JRSofty I am using my own session handler, but even if that is taken out, the code still doesn't work.

Comment: @JRSofty This is the code for the SESSION handler: http://pastebin.com/Wu00hYUT

Comment: @leo.vingi ok when you set the value from the AJAX can you see it inside the database entry for that session id? Basically saying are you absolutely sure that it is getting saved in the database?

Comment: @JRSofty I am absolutely sure that it is not being saved to the database. Because everything works only if I used sleep(1). If I don't , then the variable can't be found anywhere. Not in the database, not in the $_SESSION

Comment: @leo.vingi Have you tried this using the default session handlers? Just to make sure that your session handler code isn't causing the problem. I'm not saying I saw something that is causing the problem but using as little custom code when troubleshooting can help find where the problem lies.

Comment: @JRSofty OK, I made a mistake previously. When the custom session handler is taken out completely, everything seems to be working fine. Still a lot of debugging to do, but at least it's a step towards the right direction

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if your problem is in your write function of your session write handler. The SQL statement looks a bit odd:

Try:

```
 Core::Database()->query_execute("REPLACE INTO sessions VALUES (" . 
                                 Core::Database()->query_escape($id) . "'," . 
                                 time() . ",'" . 
                                 data = '" . Core::Database()->query_escape($data) . "')");
```

instead of:

```
 Core::Database()->query_execute("REPLACE INTO sessions SET 
                                        id = '" . Core::Database()->query_escape($id) . "',
                                        lastaccess = '" . time() . "',
                                        data = '" . Core::Database()->query_escape($data) . "'");
```

Basically use VALUES with a REPLACE instead of SET.

Comment: That didn't help, so the problem must lie somewhere else. I'm currently testing the whole site to see if I even need a custom session handler.